# accessing a variable from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            viewportFraction: 1,
          ),
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, idx, realIndex) {
            return buildImage(articles, urlImages[idx], idx, context);
          },
        ),
        DotsIndicator(
          dotsCount: 10,
          position: idx.toDouble(), //cannot access here idx value
          decorator: DotsDecorator(
            size: const Size.square(6.0),
            activeSize: const Size(22.0, 6.0),
            activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            spacing: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

DotsIndicator position should access the idx value but cannot access it. In worst case I can put DotsIndicator in buildImage class but this time the dots moving with slider which do not wish.

Without to use Getx how can I get the idx value?

Comment: The best and recommended way to do this is to use state management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options. Its better than passing the variables around. I recommend using Provider or Riverpod as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In `CarouselOptions` you can call this:

```
onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                  setState(() {
                    _current = index;
                  });
                }
```

And use `_current` anywhere

Comment: I am getting Types can't be assigned a value error

Comment: In `_current = index;` line?

Comment: yes, this line gives error. I checked again, Vscode suggested create a class names _current. I deleted the class but now VScode says _current undefined

Comment: `_current` is a example of variable. Create a global variable with the name that you want and set `index` like the code i shared

Comment: I added to global.dart currentIdx valriable and did currentIdx = index; but this is always null. There is no difference if I change the slider. (I am checking the value it in Text widget)

Comment: globals.dart
`var currentIdx;`